# Rolling Back after each test using J2EE with Jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, testing, jboss

I was using hibernate + Spring in my last project. It was very easy to setup persistence tests because using the following annotation in the top of the testing class, the changes in the database would be rolled back after each test.

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
```

Now I am using J2EE with arquillian and Jboss application server. Is there a way to do it similarly?

Answer (score 0):

As far as google tells me  `@TransactionConfiguration` is part of Spring Framework 4.0 .
So you should include Spring in your new project - even if it is for testing only.

Comment: I can't use spring, the stack currently in use is jboss

Answer (score 0):

Use an in memory db instead.  Faster and don't have to worry about rollbacks.

You can run a complete schema creation before each test, or before each suite.

Triggers, Sprocs etc more of a problem - but you shouldn't use them anyway.

Subclass this for example

```
public class BaseTest {
    private static EJBContainer ejbContainer;

        @Resource
        protected DataSource dataSource;
        protected String dataFilename = "data.sql"; // the default can be overriden in subclass

        @BeforeClass
        public static void startTheContainer() throws Exception {

            // boot the container and perform dependency injection
            final Properties p = new Properties();
            p.put("yourDB", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
            p.put("yourDB.JdbcDriver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            String schema = System.getProperty("testDatabaseSchema", "racing");
            p.put("yourDB.JdbcUrl", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:" + schema);
            p.put("yourDB.TestOnBorrow", "false");
            p.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");
            p.put("openejb.embedded.remotable", "false");
            p.put("openejb.descriptors.output", "false");
            p.put("openejb.jmx.active", "false");
            p.put("hsql.disabled", "false");

            // Logging config
            // Info from http://openejb.apache.org/configuring-logging-in-tests.html
            p.put("log4j.appender.C.layout", "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
            p.put("log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern", "%-5p %d{ABSOLUTE} %c: %m%n");
            p.put("log4j.category.OpenEJB.options", "warn");

            ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);

        }

        @AfterClass
        public static void afterClass() {
            if (ejbContainer != null) {
                ejbContainer.close();
            }
        }

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            ejbContainer.getContext()
                        .bind("inject", this);

            // check everything booted ok and is ready to go
            assertNotNull("Data source is null", dataSource);

            // setup database with SQL script
            final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            try {
                String script = getScript("schema.ddl");
                final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.execute(script);
                String dataScript = getScript(dataFilename);
                final Statement dataStatement = connection.createStatement();
                dataStatement.execute(dataScript);
                connection.commit();
            } finally {
                connection.close();
            }
        }


        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            try {
                final Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE");
                connection.commit();
            } finally {
                connection.close();
            }
        }

        protected String getScript(String scriptFilename) throws Exception {
            URL url = Resources.getResource(scriptFilename);
            return Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
        }
```

Comment: even in between tests? I mean, after running the tests for a specific junit class, will it rollback before running the test for the next class ?

Comment: @Mari We create a new db for each test - still so much quicker than using a real db.

Comment: is there any special configuration to create a new db for each test or is it the default?

Comment: @Mari see update for example, that uses hsqldb, but I prefer H2 the set up will be similar.

Comment: Saw the update in your answer. I am not sure if it is gonna work this way because I am using arquillian and h2

Comment: @Mari it would work fine with H2. Arquillian I found to be massively overblown and unnecessary. What do you get from it, over and above my snippet ?